# Definite integral power of monimials

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $r\geq 2$ an integer,  $a_{i},b_{i}\in\mathbb{R}$, for $i=1,\ldots, n$, and $a<b$ reals. Consider the integral
$$
\int_{a}^{b}[(a_{1}x-b_{1})\cdots (a_{n}x-b_{n})]^{r}dx
$$

We asume $a_{i}x-b_{i}\in [a,b]$ for each $i=1,\ldots,n$ and $x\in [a,b]$.

Does anyone know if it exists a formula (without expand the integrant) to compute the above integral?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'without develop the integrant'?

Comment: Without expand the function inside the integral